# Trying to compare tags in mongodb string array, with textbox input c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Okay so i have a mongodb that has a collection that is called videos and in videos i have a field called tags. what i want to do is compare a textbox input with the tags on all videos in the collection and return them to a gridview if a tag matches the input from the textbox. When i create a new video the tags field is a string Array so it is possible to store more than one tag. I am trying to do this in c#. Hope you some of you can help thanks!

Code for creating a new video document.

```
        #region Database Connection
        var client = new MongoClient();
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var db = server.GetDatabase("Database");
        #endregion

        var videos = db.GetCollection<Video>("Videos");
        var name = txtVideoName.Text;
        var location = txtVideoLocation.Text;
        var description = txtVideoDescription.Text;
        var user = txtVideoUserName.Text;
        string[] lst = txtVideoTags.Text.Split(new char[] { ',' });

        var index = videos.Count();
        var id = 0;

        if (id <= index)
        {
            id += (int)index;
        }

        videos.CreateIndex(IndexKeys.Ascending("Tags"), IndexOptions.SetUnique(false));

        var newVideo = new Video(id, name, location, description, lst, user);

        videos.Insert(newVideo);
```

Okay so here is how the search method looks like i have just made the syntax a little diffrent from what Grant Winney ansewred.

```
 var videos = db.GetCollection<Video>("Videos");
        string[] txtInput = txtSearchTags.Text.Split(new char[] { ',' });

        var query = (from x in videos.AsQueryable<Video>()
                     where x.Tags.ContainsAny(txtInput)
                     select x);
```

Comment: the user can specify the tags. It is possible to make a new tag if you make a ,

Comment: The user can specify more than one tag in the textbox with a , and no not all the tags has to match the ones in the textbox. It has to return the document if just some of the tags or one exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finds all videos with tags that contain a tag specified in the `TextBox`, assuming the MongoDB driver can properly translate it into a valid query.

```
var videos = db.GetCollection<Video>("Videos")
               .AsQueryable()
               .Where(v => v.Tags.Split(',')
                            .ContainsAny(txtVideoTags.Text.Split(',')))
               .ToList();
```

Make sure you've got `using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;` at the top.

Comment: This almost work. Just one more problem. It only returns one document for some reason even though there is two documents that contains the same tag

Comment: Yes it works. sorry i just had a space before on of them and that of course won't work. thank you for the help!